# Splitting a list and getting 2 variables

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
A = [['1-2'], ['10-0'], ['1-4'], ['7-20'], ['10-255'], ['10000-21']]
```

I have seen that there are similar questions but I can't solve this with that helps...
I would like to split each one of them in 2 variables, resulting at this:

```
var1 = [1, 10, 1, 7, 10, 10000]
var2 = [2, 0, 4, 7, 20, 255, 21]
```

Comment: In A, that's subtraction, it will be executed as soon as you run the cell. I guess you have inverted commas there, like A = [["1-2"], ["10-0"], .....]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
  var1 = [int(x[0].split("-")[0]) for x in A]
  var2 = [int(x[0].split("-")[1]) for x in A]
```

Comment: Then type cast it

Comment: oops, sry, not to you, i was telling to him ,By replaying to you:)

Comment: and what if I only want to do this with `['10-222]`?

Comment: then this `['10-222']` is a simple 1d list, not a 2d(your question), if it is 1d then you can simply split and take the values

Comment: If you want to do this in nd list(1d, 2d ,......) , then you can simply flatten the list and split it

Answer (score 2):

You could split those strings in a list comprehension, and unpack them into separate lists with `zip`:

```
var1, var2 = map(list,zip(*(map(int,s[0].split('-')) for s in A)))

print(var1)
# [1, 10, 1, 7, 10, 10000]
print(var2)
# [2, 0, 4, 20, 255, 21]
```

`zip` is useful here, since it helps us get from:

```
l = [list(map(int,s[0].split('-'))) for s in A]
print(l)
[[1, 2], [10, 0], [1, 4], [7, 20], [10, 255], [10000, 21]]
```

To:

```
list(zip(*l))
# [(1, 10, 1, 7, 10, 10000), (2, 0, 4, 20, 255, 21)]
```

And then we can unpack both lists into `var1` and `var2`. I'm mapping them to lists, but if tuples work this would be enough.

Comment: and what if I only want to do this with `['10-222]`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? `['10-222]` isn't in the list @yoyoyo